# What does the error opencv error assertion failed (p [-1] <= 2) mean and how to deal with it?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to translate the Mathlab code into pluses, using the OpenCV library.

On the line below:

```
resize (sig_temp, sig_temp, \
Size (sig_temp.size [0] / 2 + sig_temp.size [0]% 2, \
sig_temp.size [1] / 2 + sig_temp.size [1]% 2));
```

The program falls with an error:

```
opencv error assertion failed (p[-1] <= 2) in cv::Matsize:: operator ()
```

The previous errors `(dims <= 2, top / bottom / right / left> = 0)` were pretty obvious, because of them it was clear that the dimensions should not be more than two, the boundaries of the image should be non-negative. Immediately I do not understand what p [-1] means and why it should not be more than two (but I guess that here something is again connected with layers).

`sig_temp` - three-channel *Mat* matrix .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as i can understand from this:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/8718/files
MatSize::p is the array of dimension sizes.

p[-1] gives you amounts dimensions. maybe your sig_temp matrix is 3 dimensional or more?

my suggestion is either use its reshape method of define sig_temp as

```
cv::Mat3b sig_temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

`cv::Size` takes `int width, int height` as parameters. The 0th element of `Mat::size` is height.

```
cv::Mat img = imread("image.jpg");

cout<<img.size()<<endl; // This line prints [columns x rows]
cout<<img.size[0]<<endl; // This line prints the rows
cout<<img.size[1]<<endl; // This line prints the columns
```

So in this line:

```
Size (sig_temp.size [0] / 2 + sig_temp.size [0]% 2, \
sig_temp.size [1] / 2 + sig_temp.size [1]% 2)
```

You're giving `int height, int width` as parameters to `cv::Size` which takes `int width, int height` as params.

You should use rows and cols to avoid confusion.

```
Size (sig_temp.cols / 2 + sig_temp.cols% 2, \
    sig_temp.rows / 2 + sig_temp.rows% 2)
```

Comment: I can't use .cols and .rows 'cause it's 3-channels matrix, and in this case their value is -1.
I tried swap the indices, but error is still here.

Comment: Any RGB image is a 3 channel matrix, the rows and cols being -1 has nothing to do with the matrix having 3 channels. See if your matrix is being created correctly, try printing the matrix.

Comment: I quote a line from the documentation for the class Mat:
 the number of rows and columns or (-1, -1) when the matrix has more than 2 dimensions.
And my bebug tell me the same.

Comment: anyway, i replace those parameters by scalar (256,256) and error still there. I think we should find its meaning and then look for the it's cause. Sorry for my English if it's bad.

Comment: Channels and dimensions are two different things. You should mention in the question that the image dimensions are greater than two.

Comment: Channels are the third part of dimension, aren't they? If I tell that image have more then one channel, does not that mean that image have a third part of dimension?

Comment: @АндрейСолодовников No.

Comment: Oh, well sorry then, my fault.